# Select top 5 results then group the rest to "Other"?

Tags: mysql

How do I view the top 5 results and group the rest under "Other"? If I have a table "visits" with the field "page", it has 100 rows and I need results to be like:

```
Other    40
/        20
/about   15
/contact 10
/welcome 10
/test     5
```

I can't manage to do this in one query on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
select case when v2.page is not null 
              then v1.page 
              else 'other' 
       end, 
       count(*)
from visits v1
left join 
(
  select page, count(*) as pcount
  from visits
  group by page
  order by pcount desc
  limit 5
) v2 on v1.page = v2.page
group by case when v2.page is not null 
              then v1.page 
              else 'other' 
         end
```

Comment: I get an error when running this: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) from visits v1 left join ( select page, count(*) as pcount from visits ' at line 5"

Comment: try `count(*)` or `count(v1.some_column_of_vists)` instead of `count(v1.*)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SQL Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b116/4

SQL Left Join on W3Schools
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

```
SELECT CASE WHEN v2.page IS NOT NULL
  THEN v1.page
  ELSE 'other'
  END AS page,
  count(*) AS count
FROM visits v1
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT page, COUNT(*) AS pcount
  FROM visits
  GROUP BY page
  ORDER BY pcount DESC
  LIMIT 5
) v2 ON v1.page = v2.page
GROUP BY page
ORDER BY count DESC
```